# comparing the current url with predetermined url path

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

How can I check if the the current path is one of the following

```
http://sitename/dirname3/file1.aspx
http://sitename/dirname3/myfile.aspx
```

...

using regex.

I know how to get the current path, ie

```
string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use a regular expression, rather than just e.g.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(pathToCheck);
```

?

Comment: I suppose pathtocheck is a url path up to directory level. Wow I never thought of that. Let me try and see